# Restored model is not initialized (Inception V3/transfer learning)

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using the Inception v3 model and have applied transfer learning. The training and evaluation works nice.

Now I try to actually use the (saved) model.
I've just saved the model during training

```
print("Saving model...")
saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_path = saver.save(sess, self.MODEL_SAV_PATH)
print("...Saved @ ", save_path)
```

and try to restore it with

```
def load_model(self):     
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    self.input_shape = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, pipeline.height, pipeline.width, pipeline.channels])
    with slim.arg_scope(inception.inception_v3_arg_scope()):
        self.logits, self.end_points = inception.inception_v3(self.input_shape, num_classes=1001, is_training=False)

    self.predictions = self.end_points['Predictions']

    self.sess = tf.Session()
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(META_PATH)
    saver.restore(self.sess, train.latest_checkpoint(CHECKPOINT_PATH))
```

...

and use it finally with

```
prediction = self.sess.run(self.predictions, feed_dict={self.input_shape: converted_images}).argmax()
```

But the sess.run throws the following error

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights
 [[Node: InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights)]]
 [[Node: InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1/_795 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_2278_InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

So i guess something is not right in my restore process...

Comment: replacing ` saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(META_PATH)` with `    saver = tf.train.Saver()` would work.

Comment: thx ! Wanna make it an answer ?

Comment: sure! will post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating the graph using `self.logits, self.end_points = inception.inception_v3`, default graph already holds all the variables for that graph.

```
# replacing this one
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(META_PATH)
# with this saver would work
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```